# EC2 instance won't allow pinging

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

Ive got an EC2 instance with an iptables config as follows:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [121:8012]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [64:6240]
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
COMMIT
```

The EC2 security group has an entry for ICMP:

```
Type     Protocol     Source range     Source
All      ICMP All          N/A        0.0.0.0/0
```

But I can't ping it.  From another instance I get:

```
71 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 69999ms
```

From a Windows box at home I get:

```
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

If I remove the two ICMP related lines in the iptables conf there is no change, still can't ping it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The firewall is "allowing" ICMP Ping, but is the system answering it? Check `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` to learn if your system is ignoring Ping. Value must be 0 or Ping won't work.

Comment: Also run a `tcpdump` on the EC2 instance to see if the request packets are actually making it that far.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  changing /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all in combination with tcpdump revealing that the requests arrived but replies were dropped solved the problem.